# Solve the systems of equations in real numbers $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

Solve the simultaneus equations

$ab$ + $c$ + $d$ = $3$

$bc$ + $d$ + $a$ = $5$

$cd$ + $a$ + $b$ = $2$

$da$ + $b$ + $c$ = $6$, where $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ are real numbers.

I tried to add all of them and factor them as $xy$ + $x$ + $y$ = $(x+1)(y+1)$ - $1$. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Did you mean $da+b+c=6?$.  It would seem so by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last was supposed to be $da+b+c=6$ from the symmetry of the variables, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a*b%2Bc%2Bd%3D3,%20b*c%2Bd%2Ba%3D5,%20c*d%2Ba%2Bb%3D2,%20d*a%2Bb%2Bc%3D6) finds $a=2, b=c=0, d=3$ which is easy to verify.  It can also [solve the problem as written](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a*b%2Bc%2Bd%3D3,%20b*c%2Bd%2Ba%3D5,%20c*d%2Ba%2Bb%3D2,%20d*a%2Bb%2Ba%3D6), but the solutions are not as clean.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean da+b+c=6 :)

Comment: Is there any Mathematical solution to it?

Comment: @MathFanatics:  there is clearly a substitution solution for it.  Solve the first for $c$, substitute that into the rest, and so on.  That will get a polynomial in the last variable, which will be of no more than $8$ th degree.  Then you can use the rational root theorem.  It doesn't look easy.

Comment: @MathFanatics: Is this a problem from a course or textbook? If so, which one?

Comment: Its from the british math olympiad 2003

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple's Groebner basis package, there is a unique solution in complex numbers -- namely $(a,b,c,d) = (2,0,0,3)$, as previously noted by Ross Millikan.